# Media queries not doing the job

Tags: css, media-queries

I do have the viewport line in my code, btw. Below is my CSS - I suspect I've made an obvious error, but just am not seeing it! The text and images do flow into the expected one column, but the narrower divs remain narrow, the background image still shows, the images still full size. Please advise.

```
.cont { width:100%; max-width:1000px; position:relative; margin:0 auto; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, san serif; font-size:1em; text-align:left; }
.hdr { width:100%; max-width:1000px; position:relative; margin:0 auto; }
.row1 { width:100%; position:relative; background:url(https://myimagefiles.com/dinnerman/tbg.png); float:left;  }
.row1l { width:26%; position:relative; margin-left:2em; float:left;  }
.row1r { width:64%; position:relative; margin-left:2em; margin-right:2em; float:left;  }
.row2 { width: 94%; position:relative; text-align:left; margin:0 auto; }
.row3l { float:left; width: 45%; position:relative; text-align:left; margin:0 0 0 2em; }
.row3r { float:left; width: 45%; position:relative; text-align:left; margin:0 0 0 2em; }
.grntxt { color:#207815; }
.bott { width:100%; height:19px; )

@media only screen and (max-width: 750px) {
.cont { width:100%;  } 
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 750px) {
.hdr { width:94%;  } 
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 750px) {
.mimg { width:94%;  } 
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 750px) {
.row1 { width:94%; margin-left:.2em; margin-right:.2em; background-image:none;} 
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 750px) {
.row1l { width:94%; margin-left:.2em; margin-right:.2em; background-image:none;} 
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 750px) {
.row1r { width:94%; margin-left:.2em; margin-right:.2em; background-image:none;} 
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 750px) {
.row2 { width:94%; margin-left:.2em; margin-right:.2em; } 
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 750px) {
.row3l { width:94%; margin:0 auto; } 
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 750px) {
.row3r { width:94%; margin:0 auto; } 
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 750px) {
.bott { display:none;} 
}
```

Comment: you should group those queries, there's no point in having 13256 `@media only screen and (max-width: 750px)`

Comment: Please try to tidy up your CSS code (to better spot errors) and group your media queries together as mentioned before :)

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo

```
.bott { width:100%; height:19px; )
```

Should terminate with a `}` not a `)`

```
.bott { width:100%; height:19px; }
```

You should use a CSS linter (such as [CSSLint](https://github.com/CSSLint/csslint)) to make sure you're not making any typos. They can be run as separate tools, as part of your build chain (Grunt, Gulp, Webpack, etc.) or directly in any proper IDE (Sublime, Atom, etc.). There's also online versions like [this one](http://csslint.net/) which I used to track down the errors in your code. They're good for quick checks like this, but not suitable for a real development workflow.

Additionally, you should really group your media queries

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 750px) {
  .cont { width:100%; } 
  .hdr { width:94%; } 
  .mimg { width:94%; } 
  ...
}
```

There's no need to have separate ones for each set of styles you're applying.